# How to send post data and redirect in Node.js

Tags: node.js, redirect, post

I can send post data to remote_addr like this

```
<form action="remote_addr">
  <input name="name1" value="value1">
  <input name="name2" value="value2">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

But I want to send those post data to my action and from my action to remote_addr

```
<form action="my_action">
  <input name="name1" value="value1">
  <input name="name2" value="value2">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

my_action: function(req, res){
  //send post data to remote_addr and go to remote_addr
}
```

Comment: You could attach a handler to submit event, and perform an API call from there.